# Python: import _mysql ImportError: No module named '_mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3 and I wanted to install MySQLdb for python.I downloaded tar.gz file from this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.3/).Then extracted and `MySQLdb` folder was copied to Lib folder in Python.
 Then I tried with following code

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="",  # your password
                     db="enb")        # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor()

# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM pages")

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print (row[0])

db.close()
```

But I got error

```
import MySQLdb
  File "C:\Python34\lib\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: No module named '_mysql'
```

How can I solve this.I'm using windows 10.

Comment: pip install pymysql is a easy alternative. Did you only extract tarball ? Remember you will have to compile the package also. It has some C or C++ dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb has a C-level component that must be compiled; extracting the tarball is insufficient. Either look for a binary package for your OS and version of Python, or compile the package from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Provide permissions for `MySQL` and `_mysql` packages under Python Site-Packages.